# Use of uninitialized value

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to execute this simple code but it's already give me the following error :

**Use of uninitialized value $string in string at permutation.pl line 11.**

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;



sub message {
my ($string) = @_ ;
print "$string" ;
    }
message() ;
```

Comment: You don't pass any arguments to `message`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't pass any arguments to `message`, so its `@_` is empty, so you assigned `undef` to `$string`, which results in that warning when `$string` is stringified.

Fix:

```
message("Hello, world\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you pass non `undef` value to the function (passing no parameter at all also falls into this category), or make default value for input parameter. `//=` checks if variable is `undef` and if it is, sets right value to it (an empty string).

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


sub message {
    my ($string) = @_ ;
    $string //= "";
    print "$string" ;
}
message() ;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what //= did.